# JDBC with MySQL really slow, why

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with a really slow connection between my Java code and a MySQL remote Database when i use multiple query.

This is my code

```
ArrayList<Server_Log> ar =Server_Log_Utilities.getBy2Dates(cmb_date.getSelectedItem() + "", cmb_date2.getSelectedItem() + "");
  for (int c = 0; c < ar.size(); c++) {
     Server_Log sl = ar.get(c);

     String username = User_Utilities.getUserName(sl.getUser() + "");
     String row[] = {sl.getDate(), sl.getTime(), username, sl.getReff(), sl.getDescription()};
   }
```

but I user this code data will load fast

```
ArrayList<Server_Log> ar =Server_Log_Utilities.getBy2Dates(cmb_date.getSelectedItem() + "", cmb_date2.getSelectedItem() + "");
  for (int c = 0; c < ar.size(); c++) {
     Server_Log sl = ar.get(c);
     String row[] = {sl.getDate(), sl.getTime(),  sl.getReff(), sl.getDescription()};
  }
```

> this is User_Utilities.getUserName(sl.getUser() + ""); Method

```
 public static String getUserName(String id) {

        String UserName="";
        try {

           Connection con = new DBCon().getConnection();
                ResultSet rst = DBHandle.getData(con, "SELECT username FROM user  WHERE id='" + id + "'");
                while (rst.next()) {
                    UserName =rst.getString(1);

                }
           con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User_Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return UserName;
    }
```

> Server_Log_Utilities.getBy2Dates(cmb_date.getSelectedItem() + "",
>   cmb_date2.getSelectedItem() + ""); Method

```
 public static ArrayList getBy2Dates(String date1, String date2) {

        try {
            ar = new ArrayList<>();
            Connection con = new DBCon().getConnection();
            ResultSet rst = DBHandle.getData(con, "SELECT * FROM server_log WHERE date BETWEEN '" + date1 + "' AND '" + date2 + "' ORDER BY  `date`");
            while (rst.next()) {
                Server_Log ci = new Server_Log();
                ci.setId(rst.getInt(1));
                ci.setDate(rst.getString(2));
                ci.setTime(rst.getString(3));
                ci.setReff(rst.getString(4));
                ci.setDescription(rst.getString(5));
                ci.setUser(rst.getInt(6));
                ar.add(ci);
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Student_Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return ar;
    }
```

Comment: So, you're saying that if you remove the line that calls `User_Utilities.getUserName`, it runs fast? How about you look at what *that* code does, then.

Comment: User_Utilities.getUserName this code use for get username by user id

Comment: @GaniduDeeshan Well, it's slow. Since you're not showing its code, we can't help you.

Comment: Both methods use `new DBCon().getConnection()` and `con.close()`. Unless `DBCon` implements some kind of connection pooling, this means *creating a new connection on every call*. Establishing a database connection is **very slow**.

Comment: User `id` is a String?? Usually, id's are integers.

Comment: i convert user id to string (tostring)

Comment: If the `id` column of the `user` table is an integer (or other numeric type), then specify `WHERE id = 123`, not `WHERE id = '123'`! --- Or better yet, use a `PreparedStatement` and `WHERE id = ?`, and `setInt(1, 123)`. This way the statement doesn't change when `id` changes, which improves database SQL parsing performance.

Comment: Could you share the code for `DBHandle.getData()` and `DBCon.getConnection()`?

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a remote database, especially over a slow link, the *number* of SQL statements executed is *very* important.

This is why the JDBC API support concepts like statement batching.

In your case, you're calling `getUserName` for *every* record in `ar`. Consider ways to reduce the number of calls.

Example 1: If user is usually the same, or only a few users are generating log entries, caching the user names would eliminate redundant lookup.

Example 2: Rather than looking up the user in the client, modify the `Server_Log_Utilities.getBy2Dates` to add a `JOIN` to the User table. This way, *no* extra turn-arounds to database will be needed.

Example 3: Instead of calling `getUserName` individually in a loop, collect the user ids, and lookup the names in a batch. Use either a JDBC batch of multiple `SELECT` statements, or use a single statement with `UserId IN (?,?,?,?,...)`.